# Why aren't buttons created when running an application from Windows environment?

Tags: c++, winapi

In my code I create buttons in a child window "hwnd_top"

```
auto create_button=[](HWND hwnd, HWND hwnd_parent, RECT rect, BUTTON id){
    if(hwnd=CreateWindow(L"button", L"",
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_OWNERDRAW,
    rect.left, rect.top,
    rect.right, rect.bottom,
    hwnd_parent,
    (HMENU) id,
    nullptr, nullptr);!hwnd)
        throw ERROR_BUTTON;
};

create_button(button.menu, hwnd_top,{20,20,40,40}, BUTTON::MENU);
```

the child window is created like this:

```
hwnd_top = CreateWindowExW(0,wc.lpszClassName,(LPCTSTR) NULL, WS_CHILD, GET_INTO_RECT(wnd_rect_top), hwnd, nullptr, wc.hInstance,this)
```

When running the application through the msys2 console, the buttons are displayed correctly. But if I run the application via exe, the buttons simply do not appear. I think the problem may be related to the DLL, but then it's strange that the application starts at all. I didn't find anything strange in Dependency Walker. Here's the compilation line:

```
g++ -g main.cpp Window.cpp -o run.exe -mwindows -municode -lMsimg32 -lGdiplus
```

compiled via msys2 and cmd, behavior does not change. Moreover, if I create buttons in the main window, they are displayed correctly, regardless of the launch method

Comment: Not possible to say what is wrong without seeing more code. However the first parameter of your lambda function is strange `HWND hwnd` is a parameter, but it is effectively being used as a local variable. I suspect the problem has something to do with that. Maybe you should make it a reference instead `HWND& hwnd`, that makes more sense.

Comment: Do you have some kind of catch-all exception handler in your main, that will throw up a MessageBox with the error string/code?

Comment: @datenwolf  there is a handler, no errors occur during execution

Comment: Why is your lambda discarding the returned value of the CreateWindow?

Comment: If button.menu is supposed by assigned then that won't happen.  Either return the button's handle as a return value or pass by reference.

Comment: How do you use `WM` messages? You may need to provide more details, and a minimal reproducible example would be better.